How to deal/handle websites dynamic, ever-changing text-fields/drop-downs etc... when trying to automate the process of applying for jobs
I'm trying to use Java and Selenium to automate the process of filling out online job applications, which obviously means I need to insert text into text fields like one's name, address, phone number etc.. and even selecting options like "YES" or "NO" in drop-down-menus like the stereotypical "Will you now or in the future require sponsorship...." question...
...My question is, I do NOT obviously know which possible fields/questions will be on different companies application forms, as they logically vary/are dynamic. Is there any standardized way or efficient way to dealing with being able to fill out these "different" applications from different companies, dynamically? I don't want to hard-code the questions into my app, only to encounter a drop-down-menu with a question it has never seen before, thus rendering it unable to select a drop-down-menu option. I need a dynamic way to handle scenarios like these, so I can automate the tedious application process.
Thank you in advance!

Not impossible, but pretty much.   You might try mapping values to certain fields.  (so things like "Name", "First Name" would map to your "firstname" var... etc.. etc...) But you'd need to visit all the different sites to figure out the largest number of possible fields, and then create your maps for different name attributes.  Even then, the fields may be little odd and not have name attributes, so you'd also need to map selector methods.  There might also be an AI approach, but without proper dataset it'd be pretty hit and miss.  (Might give you a good starting point for each site, though.)

You could send the AI bot out to each new site so that it could "learn" it and then keep refining its data...

Thank you @browsermator
